# datetime as labels on x-axis blazorise line chart

Tags: blazor, blazorise

I'm trying to add a line-chart to my blazor server side project, with dates on the x-axes.

if I convert the dates tot strings, everything's fine, but I need datetime because the intervals are not constant and I want to use automatic intervals between the data points.

If I use the dates it self, as shown below, al the dates are located on the first tick of the x-axis, all lined up in a neat column.

```
 LineChart<double> lineChart;
    
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await HandleRedraw();
        }
    }

    async Task HandleRedraw()
    {
        await lineChart.Clear();
        await lineChart.AddLabels(GetDateTimeLabels());
        await lineChart.AddDataSet(GetLineChartDataset());
        await lineChart.Update();            
    }

    LineChartDataset<double> GetLineChartDataset()
    {
        return new LineChartDataset<double>
        {
            //usual stuff to build the data set
        };
    }
    
    public DateTime[] GetDateTimeLabels()
    {
        //fill array with dates
        return dateLabels;
    }
```

I tried to add an OptionJsonString to the component to a indicate that the type of the x-axis is time,  like this:

```
<LineChart @ref="lineChart" TItem="double" OptionsJsonString="@("{\"scales\": {\"xAxes\": [{\"type\": 'time'}]}}")"/>
```

But then the chart isn't rendered at all. The OptionJsonString works just fine to set min or max value of an Axes.

Could somebody give me some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it ( well, two SO users did, Henk Holterman and enet ) see: [Solution needed for Field initializer cannot reference the non-static field method or property in Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67035949/solution-needed-for-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-non-static-field-meth)