# Solution needed for Field initializer cannot reference the non-static field method or property in Blazor

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I'm working on a Blazor project, but my problem is C#. I do understand the problem, but I just can not solve it in the Blazor context.

In my razor page I use a blazorise linechart that takes dates for the x-axis. That works perfectly well if I use non-dynamic dates. The

`<LineChart @ref="lineChart" TItem="double" OptionsObject="@options"/>`

However, to determine the dates (so the x-axis labels) dynamically, I need the following code behind:

```
public partial class ChartComponent : ComponentBase
    {    
        [Parameter]
        public List<Observation> Observations { get; set; }     //an Observation has a field with a Date in it. 

        Object options = new            
        {
            Scales = new
            {
                XAxes = new[]
                {
                    new
                    {
                        labels =   new[]{GetDateTimeLabels()}   //this gets me the error, if I use new[]{DateTime.Now,...,DateTime.Now+n} it works just fine.
                    }
                }
            }
        };


public DateTime[] GetDateTimeLabels()
        {
            DateTime[] dateLabels = VACRAObservations.Select(x => x.Date).ToArray();
            return dateLabels;
        }
```

This gets me an error "a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field method or property", which I understand, because the compiler does not know if GetLabels() is ready before Object options is initialized.

I cannot go around the [Parameter], I need it to get the list of Observations into the razor page.

I tried to put it all in the constructor, but the constructor is initialized before the parameter is taken in.

I tried to do it with statics, but a static class can not derive from Componentbase class.

I'm at a loss what to do. Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest fix is to make it a property. When you only need it once, add a `>` :

```
 Object options => new   {  ...  };
```

and when you need to guard against evaluating it too often:

```
 Object _options = null;
 Object options => _options ?? (_options = new            
    {
        ... // as before
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Henk, both your and enets method work. You were first. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Henk en enet:

```
<LineChart @ref="lineChart" TItem="double" OptionsObject="@Options"/>
```

And this is the working partial class

````
public partial class xxxComponent : ComponentBase
    {
        public void Refresh()
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        }
               
        [Parameter]
        public List<Observation> Observations { get; set; }
                
        Object Options =>
           new
           {
               Scales = new
               {
                   XAxes = new[]
                       {
                        new
                           {
                            labels =  GetDateTimeLabels()  //changed to avoid a 2 dimensional array  
                           }
                       }
               }
           };
      
        LineChart<double> lineChart;
       
        protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        {
            if (firstRender)
            {
                await HandleRedraw();
            }
        }

        async Task HandleRedraw()
        {
            await lineChart.Clear();
            await lineChart.AddDataSet(GetLineChartDataset());
            await lineChart.Update();
        }

        LineChartDataset<double> GetLineChartDataset()
        {
            return new LineChartDataset<double>
            {
                Label = "VA",
                Data = GetVALevels(),
                Fill = false,
                PointRadius = 2,
                BorderDash = new List<int> { },

            };
        }
        
        public DateTime[] GetDateTimeLabels()
        {
            DateTime[] dateLabels = Observations.Select(x => x.Date).ToArray();
            return dateLabels;
        }

        public List<double> GetVALevels()
        {
            List<double> vALevels = Observations.Select(x => x.VA).ToList();
            return vALevels;
        }
  }```
````